# Service worker in progressive web apps returns nothing in console

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, service-worker

I'm training Progressive Web apps from Google labs, Here in a specific chapter there is to need setup the service worker script and check whether it will result the thing in console according to guidance provided in the lab instructions.

As I did all the instructions correctly,but the console returns empty whenever I reload the page to check whether the code is working.

Can any one tell me whats the actual problem with the code?

[Google PWA training labs](https://google-developer-training.gitbooks.io/progressive-web-apps-ilt-codelabs/content/docs/lab_scripting_the_service_worker.html)

And here is the code which Google code labs instructed me to do.

```
  <script>
  (function(){
    'use strict';
    // TODO - 2: Register the service worker
    if (!('serviceWorker' in navigator)) {
    console.log('Service worker not supported');
    return;
    }
    navigator.serviceWorker.register('service-worker.js')
    .then(function(registration){
        console.log('Registered');
    })
    .catch(function(error)         {
           console.log('Registeration failed:', error);
    });
  })
  </script>`
```

**Note: The solution code(Provided from google) inside my local machine is working perfectly and service worker is registered, active , installed, and fetching.**

Comment: how about giving this function a name and then calling it. From what i can see you have written function and you haven't called it either you have to go with first  way i told or you can just put "()" at the end of your code to create a self calling function

Comment: as mentioned by orangespark, try putting () at the end of paranthesis enclosing function

Comment: Really, I did it first and its my bad to check the code. 

Thank you @orangespark

Comment: Can anyone close this question as solved? I am not aware of it

Comment: I think we will have to flag it in that case it might lead to some negative effect to you